# How to display images from a JSON file URL (localhost storage)

Tags: php, json

i'm trying to make images appear on my webpage from a JSON file. The code I have below gets the image, and puts it in the page, but this is what shows on my page:
[Webpage when I execute the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLvyf.png). So if anyone could help me pinpoint where I might've gone wrong in my code, that would be good thanks.
I dont want to use the image file directly, I need to have it go through localhost.
Also, yes, when I search the image URL, the photos do show up.

```
<?php
    
      $output = file_get_contents("ratings.json");
      
      $decode = json_decode($output, true);
    
      for($i = 0; $i < count($decode); $i++) {
    
      $imgUrl = $decode[$i]['image'];
    
    ?>
    
    <html>
      <body>
    
        <img src="<?php$imgUrl?>" height="70" width="70" class="img-thumbnail" /> <?php
        echo $imgUrl;
        }
        
        ?>
      </body>
    </html>
```

JSON File:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test",
        "review": "Test",
        "rating": "5",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/RobloxScreenShot20210104_132131740.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "The Storytellers",
        "review": "Test",
        "rating": "5",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/RobloxScreenShot20201012_195012147.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "ACTivate children's club for 3-4 years",
        "review": "Test",
        "rating": "4",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/RobloxScreenShot20210101_181318133.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "Flexibility and core training",
        "review": "Was so good for my core",
        "rating": "5",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/RobloxScreenShot20201120_213311711.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "The Letter 'B'",
        "review": "SO Cool",
        "rating": "1",
        "image": "http:\/\/localhost\/ClassIA3\/images\/untitled.png"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here. Try this:

```php
<html>
<body>
<?php
$output = file_get_contents("ratings.json");
$decode = json_decode($output, true);
for($i = 0; $i < count($decode); $i++) {
    $imgUrl = $decode[$i]['image'];
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imgUrl; ?>" height="70" width="70" class="img-thumbnail" /> <?php echo $imgUrl; ?>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

You don't want to start your HTML markup in the loop, it will be repeated for each image. Also, when you set the src attribute in the img tag, you need to echo the $imgUrl variable.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative foreach solution:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $output = file_get_contents("ratings.json");
    $decode = json_decode($output, true);
    foreach($decode as $val)
    {
        $imgUrl = $val['image'];
    ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $imgUrl; ?>" height="70" width="70" class="img-thumbnail" />
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</body>
```